# Making Loop in xPath() : Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object

Tags: php, xml

I want to making loop with xpath() with this function:

```
function rs(){

$rs = array();
$cities = array("city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", "city5",
    "city6", "city7", "city8");
foreach ($cities as $value) {

    $rs[] = $xmls->xpath("area[city= '$value']");

}
return $rs; }

$rs = rs();
```

Edit:

```
function meteor(){

$request_url = "http://meteoroloji.gov.tr/FTPDATA/analiz/sonSOA.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("feed not loading");
return $xml;}
$xmls = meteor();
```

with `print_r($rs);` I have `Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object`. Is my function wrong? (Im not familliar with OOP)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$xmls` is not in scope, as simple as that. Pass it as an argument (`rs($xmls)`), or set it as an attribute if this is a method from a class rather then a standalone function (and it if that would be more logical).

Comment: Provide the example of the function with an argument, and the code you use to call the function, and maybe we can see more. As it stand _"it's not working too"_ isn't a problem description that is of any use to us.

Comment: @Wrikken; Thanks for help, With "it's not working too" means that I have the same error with argument. With global $xmls there is no error. 
I want to know why argument doesnt work in this OOP case.

Comment: @phpExe: I refer you to my previous statement: _"Provide the example of the function with an argument, and the code you use to call the function, and maybe we can see more"_, without it this is just inane guesswork :)

Comment: So, what happens if you alter the `function res(){` to `function rs($xmls){`, and call `$rs = rs(meteor());`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object

Comment: Could you pastebin your current code somewhere so I could check locally? I find this all very odd.

Comment: @Wrikken, your answer has solved my problem. Thank you very much.